How can I compose iterator adapter without boilerplate each time like in node.js Readable.compose
I want to be able to compose iterators that even support genawaiter crate and avoid the boilerplate for every iterator adapter
I want to be able to iterator.compose(fn) like below (I know I can use the map operator but this is a simplified example for when I need to have some state in the iterators):
use genawaiter::{rc::gen, yield_};
use std::iter::Iterator;

fn wrap_with_option<Input, I: Iterator<Item = Input>>(iter: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = Option<Input>> {
    return gen!({
            for item in iter {
                yield_!(Some(item));
            }
        })
    .into_iter();
}
fn run() {

    let input: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let output: Vec<Option<&i32>> = input
        .iter()
        .compose(wrap_with_option)
        .collect();

    let expected = vec![
        Some(&1),
        Some(&2),
        Some(&3),
        Some(&4),
        Some(&5)
    ];
    assert_eq!(output, expected);
}


"I want to be able to do this" - and what's the problem with this code? What exactly is your question here?

@Bergi tried to improve the wording ther

There is the tap crate that provides this general functionality. It provides methods to use function calls in a method-chained way.
You would use the .pipe() method via its Pipe trait.
use tap::Pipe;

let output: Vec<Option<&i32>> = input
    .iter()
    .pipe(wrap_with_option)
    .collect();


You can do this:
it will work with any function that gets an iterator and returns an iterator,
It just implement the compose function on the global iterator that get a function and execute it on the current iterator (self) and return the function result - new iterator
use std::iter::Iterator;

pub trait Compose: Sized {
    fn compose<F, R>(self, f: F) -> R
    where F: FnOnce(Self) -> R {
        f(self)
    }
}
impl<T> Compose for T {}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use genawaiter::{rc::gen, yield_};

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn should_allow_changing_the_input_type() {
        let input = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        let output: Vec<String> = input
            .iter()
            .compose(|iter| iter.map(|x| x.to_string()))
            .collect();

        let expected = vec![
            "1".to_string(),
            "2".to_string(),
            "3".to_string(),
            "4".to_string(),
            "5".to_string(),
        ];
        assert_eq!(output, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn should_allow_multiple_compositions() {
        let input = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        let output: Vec<String> = input
            .iter()
            .compose(|iter| iter.map(|x| x.to_string()))
            .compose(|iter| iter.map(|x| x + "!"))
            .collect();

        let expected = vec![
            "1!".to_string(),
            "2!".to_string(),
            "3!".to_string(),
            "4!".to_string(),
            "5!".to_string(),
        ];
        assert_eq!(output, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn should_allow_multiple_compositions_that_change_type() {
        #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
        struct MyStruct {
            value: String,
        }
        let input = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        let output: Vec<MyStruct> = input
            .iter()
            .compose(|iter| iter.map(|x| x.to_string()))
            .compose(|iter| iter.map(|x| MyStruct { value: x }))
            .collect();

        let expected = vec![
            MyStruct {
                value: "1".to_string(),
            },
            MyStruct {
                value: "2".to_string(),
            },
            MyStruct {
                value: "3".to_string(),
            },
            MyStruct {
                value: "4".to_string(),
            },
            MyStruct {
                value: "5".to_string(),
            },
        ];
        assert_eq!(output, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn should_support_gen() {
        fn wrap_with_option<Input, I: Iterator<Item = Input>>(iter: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = Option<Input>> {
            return gen!({
                for item in iter {
                    yield_!(Some(item));
                }
            })
            .into_iter();
        }

        let input: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        let output: Vec<Option<&i32>> = input
            .iter()
            .compose(wrap_with_option)
            .collect();

        let expected = vec![
            Some(&1),
            Some(&2),
            Some(&3),
            Some(&4),
            Some(&5)
        ];
        assert_eq!(output, expected);
        
    }
}


Your ComposeByIterator is needlessly specific and generally just a weird way to write foo.compose(f) instead of the much simpler f(foo)

The use case is 10 composed functions, and this will have f10(f9(f8(f7(f6(f5(f4(f3(f2(f1())))))))))

Updated the code to use your suggestion I'm new to rust

"I'm new to Rust" – Then I strongly advise you write Rust instead of trying to force node.js concepts into Rust. That seldomly leads to idiomatic or good code.
